# Room Insert only inserts the primary key and not columns

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am trying to insert an object into my room database but only the primary key seems to be inserted. The additional String List and Integer List are both null when I try to acess them.

Entity

```
@Entity
public class DayMenu{
@PrimaryKey @NonNull
private String dayDate;


@TypeConverters(IntegerConverter.class)
private List<Integer> dayRecipesID;

@TypeConverters(StringConverter.class)
private List<String> dayRecipesTitle;
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface DayMenuDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertDayMenu(DayMenu dayMenu);

@Query("select * from DayMenu")
List<DayMenu> getAll();

@Query("select * from DayMenu")
LiveData<List<DayMenu>> getAllLD();

@Query("select dayDate from DayMenu where DayMenu.dayDate = :day_date")
DayMenu getFromDate(String day_date);
}
```

When I look at dayMenu (below) it will have the two Lists with the correct data just before I send it to be inserted. However that information is either not inserted or is not being recovered when I call getAll(), getAllLD() or getFromDate().

MainActivity

```
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (etDate.getText().length() != 0) {
                String currentDate = etDate.getText().toString();

                DayMenu dayMenu = new DayMenu();
                dayMenu.setDayDate(currentDate);

                List<Integer> recIDs = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> recTits = new ArrayList<>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int childCount = linearLayoutParent.getChildCount();
                if (childCount > 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
                        View linearLayoutChild = linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(i);
                        ViewGroup lLC = (ViewGroup) linearLayoutChild;
                        Button recipeButton = (Button) lLC.getChildAt(0);
                        recIDs.add(Integer.parseInt(recipeButton.getTag().toString()));
                        recTits.add(recipeButton.getText().toString());

                    }

                    dayMenu.setDayRecipesID(recIDs);
                    dayMenu.setDayRecipesTitle(recTits);

                    for(String str : dayMenu.getDayRecipesTitle()){
                        sb.append(str).append(", ");
                    }

new AsyncIns(mViewModel.GetDayMenuDao(),dayMenu).execute();

                    Toast.makeText(_context, sb,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    NoRecipesAddedHandler(_context);
                }
            }
            else{
                NoDateSelectedHandler(_context);
            }
        }
    });
```

AsyncTask

```
    private class AsyncIns extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DayMenu>{
    final DayMenuDao mDao;
    final DayMenu mDM;

    AsyncIns(DayMenuDao dao, DayMenu dm){
        mDao = dao;
        mDM = dm;
    }

    @Override
    protected DayMenu doInBackground(Void... params){
        mDao.insertDayMenu(mDM);
        return mDao.getFromDate(mDM.getDayDate());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DayMenu d){
        Toast.makeText(_context,d.getDayDate(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This will display the date saved to the database, and I have been able to see the dates with other methods. However, when I try and access the recipeIds and titles the Lists are null.

I am not really sure what is going wrong, it seems like insertDayMenu is only inserting the Entities primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stetho Library to see what is actually in the Database:

add this line to your build.gradule module file:

```
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
```

then add an Application.java file like so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Context context = getBaseContext();

        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

    }
}
```

then add in the manifest file: in the application tag add:

```
android:name="MyApplication"
```

when your app is running open google chrome and enter:

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

you should see your app - inspect it and you'll see what is in the database

Also I just noticed you are using camelcase for your names, that is very good for Java but not for the database:

Your code needs to look like this:

```
@TypeConverters(IntegerConverter.class)
@SerializedName("day_recipes_id")
@Expose
private List<Integer> dayRecipesID;

@TypeConverters(StringConverter.class)
@SerializedName("day_recipes_title")
@Expose
private List<Integer> dayRecipesTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite can not have the datatype List<>.
Maybe you want a one to many relationship for those fields? Where one DayMenu can have many DayRecipes.